# Why can't I retrieve the inserted data instantaneously from Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a RDS postgres db. When i try to retrieve the recently inserted data, it's retrieving for some occasion and it's not for other occasions. I'm calling my node API from a react front end. Ex, after an insertion,

This query is retrieving the data instantaneously. Here id is the PK of the table.

```
SELECT * from glacier_restore_progress where id in (1,2,3);
```

But

```
select *
from glacier_restore_progress
where email='ahk@gmail.com' and restore_expire >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
order by restore_start;
```

above query is not retrieving the data instantaneously. I'm calling the endpoint again and again to fetch the data (ie polling). after certain number of calls, it's returning.

But when i see the db via the dbeaver client the records are there as soon after i insert them.

table schema

```
create table glacier_restore_progress(
id SERIAL NOT NULL ,
file_path VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
restore_start timestamp,
restore_end timestamp,
restore_expire timestamp,
status VARCHAR(10),
file_data_obj jsonb,
field_mapping jsonb,
primary key (id)
);
```

The library i'm using "pg": "8.5.1".

What am i missing here?

Comment: Was it inserted in a Transaction that was not yet committed? If you are inserting via dBeaver and selecting them from the same session, it might see the pre-committed data.

Answer (score 0):

I only work with Node.js and Postgre for only a while. My answer might not be good. But based on what I know, one of the issues might be caching. Sometimes your browser stores the cached data, and only update after a certain time interval.

If you wish to use real-time application, you might need externally library that can help supports real-time application, or find a workaround with WebSocket.